# Servlet calling a method of a class in another server

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to JAVA servlet/server programming. I am trying to get the servlet to call the `getInstance()` method of an instantiated class from a server. I have pasted below the server code, which registers a client class and instantiates it. This runs with no errors

```
public class RelevanceClient {

private static RelevanceClient client;
public final static String LOGSOURCE = "RELEVANCECLIENT";

private HistogramClient histogramClient;
private UserClient userClient;
private LoadBalancer loadBalancer = null;

static {
    try {
        SystemRegistrar.register();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Object args[] = {e};
        Log.logException(e);
        Log.logMessage(LOGSOURCE, Log.ERROR,
            RelevanceClientRes.get(RelevanceClientRes.FAILED_TO_REGISTER, args));
        client = null;
    }
}

public static void registerClient(RelevanceClient _client) { client = _client; }

/**
 * Returns instance of RelevanceClient
 */
public static RelevanceClient getInstance() throws RelevanceClientException {
    if (client == null)
        throw new RelevanceClientException(
            RelevanceClientRes.get(RelevanceClientRes.CLIENT_INIT_ERR));
    return client;
}
```

Now, I have a servlet code calling getInstance() to get the class. I get a client class not registered error even though I am encountering no error when I registered the client in the server.

```
public class Relevance extends HttpServlet {

private final static String P_CMD    = "cmd";

public final static String SERVLET_INFO = "eSelf relevance servlet";

ServletConfig config = null;
RelevanceClient client = null;

private Hashtable commandMap = new Hashtable();

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    this.config = config;
    try {
        client = RelevanceClient.getInstance();
    } catch(Exception rootCause) {
        client = null;
        throw new ServletException(ServletRes.get(ServletRes.RCLIENT_INIT_ERR), rootCause);
    }
    Log.logMessage(Log.INFO, ServletRes.get(ServletRes.SERVLET_INIT));
}
```

Is what I am doing incorrect or illegal in some ways? I appreciate any clue. The full error message is below.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error obtaining relevance client
eself.tool.servlet.Relevance.init(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

root cause:

```
eself.client.relevance.RelevanceClientException: Relevance client was not registered successfully
eself.client.relevance.RelevanceClient.getInstance(Unknown Source)
eself.tool.servlet.Relevance.init(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Comment: You never(?) calls `registerClient()`. So `RelevanceClient.client` is always `null`.

Comment: @PeterMmm, I have updated the question with the error message

Comment: @PeterMmm, on the server side, I do have the `RelevenaceClient.client` value set.  On the client side, I initialize the `RelevanceClient  client` to be null. I then get the instance from the server and store the value on my servlet. Is that not OK to do?

Comment: I don't get you with this server/client side. I can only guess you have a `doGet()` anywhere, but you don't show the code. Anyway, as this happens all in the servlet's init, the `if (client == null)` branch always true, because `client` is never assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

RelevanceClient.client is always null in the code. So the initialization will fail always.